# Example of non measurable function in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

I'm looking for a function $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ which is non-measurable. I have no ideas about this.

I know that if we have non-measurable sets in a measure space, there are non-measurable functions from that space.

Comment: If $A\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ is not measurable then indicator function $\mathbf1_A$ is not measurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every subset of $\mathbb R^{2}$ is a measurable set. If $A$ is a non-measurable set then define $f(x)=1$ for $ x \in A$ and $f(x)=0$ for $ x \in A^{c}$. Then $f$ is not measurable.

If $E$ is not measurable in $\mathbb R$ then $E \times \mathbb R$ is not measurable in $\mathbb R^{2}$. For an example of such a set $E$ see https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Non-measurable_set

Comment: I agree with this statement, I don't say that every subset of $R^2$ is a measurable set

Comment: @EgorKurito There is  a famous example of a non-measurabe set constructed by Vitali. See the link I have added to my answer.

Comment: Interesting property. Can it be generalized like this: if we have a nonempty set $A \subset R^2$, $B \subset R$, $A$ is non-measurabe set. Does is $A \times B$ measurabe?

Comment: please , could you explain why?

Comment: Thanks). It's help me.

Comment: @KaboMurphy: what you said in your last comment is not true. Take $E\subset\mathbb R$ not Lebesgue-measurable. Then $E\times \mathbb Q$ is Lebesgue-measurable on $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Your answer is fine. As for the measure, the question has the tag "Lebesgue measure".  It would never occur to me that "measurable without a qualifier means Borel.